How many iterations should an algorithm go over its average number of iterations?
Introduction. Pollard's Rho is a factoring algorithm.  Given an integer such as $77$, it splits the integer into two factors.  In this case, it splits $77$ into $(7, 11)$ when it succeeds.  It's a probabilistic algorithm.  When it doesn't succeed, you can always restart it changing random input to the method but keeping the same integer you want to factor, so that it the method eventually does split the integer.
There is a heuristic argument that says that the number of iterations that the method requires to split $N$ is $\sqrt[4]{N}$ on average.
The problem.  Consider an implementation of the method that counts how many iterations it has performed.  As it gets close to $\sqrt[4]{N}$ iterations, we could say it is (on average) approaching the desired answer.  However, because the method might never find an answer in some cases, we also need to stop it at some point if it didn't yet find a correct answer.  Implementations I've seen arbitrarily put a limit without any mathematical or statistical argument.  How to properly choose this limit?
I have very little knowledge of probability and statistics, but my little knowledge says that I could answer this question in terms of the probability of success.  Say I want the algorithm to have 95% percent of success among numbers of certain size.  What must I learn about the method to figure out when to stop the method, giving up on that integer?

Have you simulated it?  You're interested in the value of starting with a new seed.  Computing the real cost of various seeds vs various $N$ could be informative.

"As it gets close to $\sqrt[4]{N}$ iterations, we could say it is (on average) approaching the desired answer." ... that depends what you mean. If you're saying "if I waited the expected time, I should be due to see it soon", not necessarily. If the random inputs are such that the process is effectively a series of independent Bernoulli trials, then no, the lack of memory property of the geometric would suggest you're no "closer to done" after any given wait time. e.g. if I roll a 20 sided die until I see a 1, my expected wait is 20 rolls, but if I waited 20 rolls and don't see one, ... ctd

ctd... my remaining expected wait now is still another 20 rolls. On the other hand if it's like drawing cards from a deck (draw until I see A♠), then I do in some sense become nearer to "due". If I drew half the deck without getting it (drawing half the deck is the expected wait time), I'm now twice as likely to see it on the next draw as I was at the start, and I cannot wait more than that long again. Not being a number theory person, some additional clarity about the nature of the problem is needed.

I could read the paper to (hopefully) try to get a sense of how the "randomness" might be modeled, but such contextual information would be better provided in the question, or at least a more detailed description would be helpful to help clarify what sort of problem it might be. If that's not possible, Him's suggestion of actually trying it to see how it behaves is a good starting point. Sometimes simulation experiments can be a little misleading  though (observed behavior at small N may not carry over to very large N, for example, and it's possible to be somewhat misled if you extrapolate).

If the trials are truly independent with constant probability (the binomial d20 model I started with), the number of trials to get some pre-specified probability of success can be computed fairly readily. It's not completely clear to me yet that this is the right model to apply though. If it is, the lack of memory property would still apply. Let's say you came up with 150 attempts to get a 95% probability and didn't get it. You still wouldn't be "due"; your expected wait is still whatever it was.

It looks like the 2008 paper by Shi Bai and Richard P. Brent has some relevant information both theoretical (given an assumption) and empirical. https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb231.pdf though for me it would require building some additional understanding before getting to the beginnings of a useful response.

@Glen_b, I totally agree with everything you said.  What's the meaning of $N^{1/4}$ iterations on average?  By the way, the trials are certainly not random because we pseudorandom sequences are used, but (interestingly), it is precisely the pseudorandomness that is desired.  With true randomness, there would not be the number-theoretic properties needed to split the number in the estimated number of iterations.  (That's a side story.  We assume randomness because, otherwise, nobody knows how to estimate the runtime of the method.)

@Him, I've simulated.  It would take some time for me to present everything I know about the method.  I did see the simulation looking very much like $N^{1/4}$ on average.  There are some bad cases that go well beyond it, but they're few.  So I believe there's some argument to be made here that we should not chase the 3% or 5% or 7% of these bad cases.  While this may make no difference in practice, at least there would be an argument instead of guesses in the implementation of the algorithm.
